# Grep regex to extract only the subdomains

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I have this list in a file on my Linux machine:

```
sub1.site.com
sub2.site.com.edgekey.net
subs.site.com.trafficmanager.com
sub3.site.com
```

I want to select the following from that list:

sub.site.com

And nothing that has anything after `site.com`, like `edgekey` or `trafficmanager`. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome, have you tried something so far?

Comment: I Was Grepping CNAME From dig Results, They Were Like ``sub.site.com IN CNAME cname.3rdparty.com`` so I used awk '{print $1}'. But Many Of Them Has CNAME of CNAME. So My List Also Included Them After awk.
So i Did grep "site.com". But Many Of Them had "sub.site.com.edgekey.net", "sub.site.com.anything.com"
So I want To Grep Only Those Ends With "site.com" and Nothing after this

Comment: What is the expected output? Add it to your question.

Comment: What if there's a `sub.site.net`? Or it's all just `.com`?

Comment: Please put your update into your question. Don't leave it in the comments because that makes it harder for people to notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `cut`.

```bsh
cut -d '.' -f1-3 file
```

print only the first three fields using the dot as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

This finds the lines with exactly 3 dot-separated fields:

```bsh
awk -F'.' 'NF == 3' filename
```

```
sub1.site.com
sub3.site.com
```

This omits "sub2" -- you don't specify if that's what you want or not.